# How to convert line breaks in a text file between the Windows and Unix/Linux formats?

Tags: linux, windows, unix

How do I convert line breaks in a text file between the Windows and Unix/Linux formats?

I have a *nix environment, but that I need to import and export data with the Windows-style line breaks.  I thought there would be a standard utility or command to do this, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You're probably looking for `dos2unix`, `unix2dos`, `todos` or `fromdos` depending on your distribution. Ubuntu/Debian package `todos`/`fromdos` as part of the **tofrodos** package from memory.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this question looking for Windows solutions, the upstream site for `dos2unix` is http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html, and it works in Windows as well.

Comment: You can install [`dos2unix`/`unix2dos`](http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html) on Mac OS X using [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/). With Homebrew installed, the command is `brew install dos2unix`, which uses [this formula](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/dos2unix.rb).

Answer (score 24):

One option is to use `unix2dos` (and `dos2unix` for going back) on the command line.

Another is to use a text editor:
For vi: :set ff=dos to set the line endings to be dos line endings.
For emacs: C-x [ENTER] f dos [ENTER]

For your favourite GUI based editor (eg. jedit) I recommend checking the manual or Google.

Lastly if you don't want to deal with a text editor and just do it using more common utilities and such (or don't have unix2dos installed):

`tr -d '\r' < infile > outfile` to go from Windows -> Unix
`awk 'sub("$", "\r")' unixfile.txt > winfile.txt` to go from Unix -> Windows as `tr` can not go from Unix to Windows.

Comment: dos2unix made the trick, however thanks for tr utility, it could have saved so much time in the past!

Comment: If a file has mixed line endings, make sure to load it in proper `ff`: `:e ++ff=unix`. At least it makes sense for `dos -> unix` conversion.

Comment: That awk one liner is teaching a man to fish, thanks for that. I'll be slightly less hungry in future

Answer (score 13):

Edit it in Vim and use the `set fileformat` command.

- MS-DOS/Windows (CR+LF breaks) to *nix (LF only breaks)

  ```
  :set fileformat=unix
  :wq
  ```
- *nix to MS-DOS/Windows

  ```
  :set fileformat=dos
  :wq
  ```

Comment: Be careful when using that if the file does not already have a line break at the last line; vim will add one unless you know how to tell it not to.

Comment: After hours of trying every other solution this was the lifesaver I needed. Confirmed behaviour on OS X Yosemite with `hexdump -C` -- also confirmed this is *not* sticky -- it is set per `vi` session

Answer (score 8):

This is what I use, similar to Chealion, to convert Windows to Unix line endings:

```
tr -d \\015 < windows > unix
```

Comment: The poster wanted unix to windows line endings. And you're some years late with you answer.

Comment: Who cares if it's "years late"? It still works, and it's still applicable to the question. I was just adding another option for readers that come upon it, like myself. Also, his question asks for Windows -> Unix, and his description asks for Unix -> Windows. *shrug*

Comment: Right. Maybe you add the other tr-command for converting unix to windows then.

Comment: I tried to undo the downvote, but it said that it's locked until the article is edited.

Comment: @ott-- no problem, I upvoted for you. ...wait, now *I* can't upvote for me! ...dang... :)

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with POSIX is tricky:

- [POSIX Sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) does not support `\r` or `\15`. Even if it did, the in place
  option `-i` is not POSIX
- [POSIX Awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) does support `\r` and `\15`, however the `-i inplace` option
  is not POSIX
- *d2u* and *dos2unix* are not [POSIX utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html), but *ex* is
- [POSIX ex](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) does not support `\r`, `\15`, `\n` or `\12`

To remove carriage returns:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\1";ORS="";getline;gsub("\r","");print>ARGV[1]}' file
```

To add carriage returns:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\1";ORS="";getline;gsub("\n","\r&");print>ARGV[1]}' file
```