# How to convert text file from Windows line breaks to Unix ones on Windows?

Tags: windows, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert text file from Windows line breaks to Unix ones on Unix/Linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/6134/how-to-convert-text-file-from-windows-line-breaks-to-unix-ones-on-unix-linux)

Basically the same question as [How to convert line breaks in a text file between the Windows and Unix/Linux formats?](https://serverfault.com/questions/6134/how-to-convert-text-file-from-windows-line-breaks-to-unix-ones-on-unix-linux), but for a Windows machine.

Thanks, Kevin

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. The other answer details two ways to do it without utilities in a unix shell. It would be useful to know how to do it in a windows shell as well (I can't find it anywhere on the web so it would be great to find this out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Same answer](http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html).